How to Transfer 5-Minute Boxes to 1-Minute Timeframe in Pine Script without Changing Their Position or Count?
I am currently working on a Pine Script project where I need to transfer boxes drawn on a 5-minute timeframe to a 1-minute timeframe. My goal is to do this without changing the position or the number of the boxes.
I have already tried various methods and commands, but I haven’t been successful. When I use the most recommendable "request.security" function, the boxes get misaligned and duplicated strangely on the 1-minute timeframe.
Even after consulting AI tools like ChatGPT, I haven't received a satisfactory solution.
Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I attempted to use the request.security function to fetch the box coordinates from the 5-minute timeframe and plot them on the 1-minute timeframe. However, this resulted in the boxes being misaligned and duplicated.
I explored various methods of storing the box coordinates in arrays or variables but still faced issues when trying to render them accurately on the lower timeframe.
I expected that by using request.security, the boxes would transfer over to the 1-minute timeframe with the same positions and counts as they had on the 5-minute timeframe, without any duplication or misalignment. Additionally, I hoped to retain the original box data so I could continue working with them, as the current results make them unusable.
here is the code:
//@version=5
indicator("Fair Value Gaps", "FVG", overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500)

// Inputs
ext = input.int(10, "Extend FVGs")
upcolor = input.color(defval = #2962ff, title = "Bullish color", group = "Aesthetics")
downcolor = input.color(defval = #e91e63, title = "Bearish color", group = "Aesthetics")
inp1 = input.bool(false, "Volume Filter", group = "Filters")
inp2 = input.bool(false, "ATR Filter", group = "Filters")
inp3 = input.bool(false, "Trend Filter", group = "Filters")

// Variables for filtering and FVG calculations
var bool bfvg = false
var bool sfvg = false
var float fvg_top = na
var float fvg_bottom = na
var bool confirmedBullish = false
var bool confirmedBearish = false
var bool entrySignalBullish = false
var bool entrySignalBearish = false
var bool tradeTaken = false  // Flag to track if trade is taken


// Identify bullish and bearish FVGs based on 5-minute chart
fvg_bullish_top = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", low)
fvg_bullish_bottom = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", high[2])
fvg_bearish_top = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", high)
fvg_bearish_bottom = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", low[2])


// Detect Bullish FVG
if low > high[2] and not na(fvg_bullish_top) and not na(fvg_bullish_bottom)
    bfvg := true
    box.new(left = bar_index - 2, top = fvg_bullish_top, right = bar_index + ext, bottom = fvg_bullish_bottom, border_color = color.new(color.gray, 100), bgcolor = color.new(upcolor, 85))
   

// Detect Bearish FVG
if high < low[2] and not na(fvg_bearish_top) and not na(fvg_bearish_bottom)
    sfvg := true
    box.new(left = bar_index - 2, top = fvg_bearish_top, right = bar_index + ext, bottom = fvg_bearish_bottom, border_color = color.new(color.gray, 100), bgcolor = color.new(downcolor, 85))
    






I tested your code. Can you please add an example oder picture of what you want to achieve resp. what the boxes should look like on a chart? If you use a 1 minute time frame and want the boxes to be drawn every 5 minutes you should consider using the time() function

Thank you for the response! I want the boxes to simply be copied to the exact same position as they are on the 5-minute timeframe. Just like when you manually draw a box on the 5-minute timeframe and then switch to the 1-minute timeframe, the same box appears in the same place. I need it to automatically transfer those FVGs from the 5-minute to the 1-minute timeframe without changing their position, so that I can create a strategy where if the price action enters the 5-minute FVG on the 1-minute timeframe and makes a reaction, it will automatically enter a trade.

Currently, I don’t know why it isn’t working properly. Firstly, there are way too many boxes being drawn, and secondly, everything seems to be shifted to the right.

I might have time on the weekend to work on your code, till then 2 recommendations: First, you don´t need 4 request calls, you can do [open_5min, high_5min, low_5min, close_5min] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", [open, high, low, close]) and then access the previous values as you did with low_5min[x]. Second, I suggest you give your variables proper names if you work with different time frames, the high and  low[2] you use for detection are for the 1 minute time frame, IMO that´s why you get many boxes

Thank you, for the suggestions! I appreciate the tips on optimizing the request calls and variable naming—it makes sense, and I’ll definitely incorporate that structure to keep things clear across timeframes. I actually managed to solve the issue with the excessive boxes, so your advice already helped steer me in the right direction. Thanks again for your time and guidance!

you are welcome! I learned something from you, I wasn´t aware of the FVG concept before and I like it. BTW, I found a public FVG indicator on Tradingview where you can choose a second time frame: FVG by spacemanbtc
